# google script to update submitted form response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to update a submitted formResponse from a script? I've tried using withItemResponse() but it fails because the form has already been submitted. Users can update a submitted formResponse using the editUrl. I want to do this programmatically with a script.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to edit the responses once they have been recorded to a spreadsheet.  There is no way to edit them "on-the-fly" or edit them if they are only tracked in the form.  You are correct that withItemResponse() only works with responses that have been programmaticly generated before you call submit();

The big work around is that you can, on every response, getResponses(). Delete  all the stored responses, .deleteAllResponses(), as you cannot delete individual formResponses. Then rebuild them with the additional responseItems that you want, using  .createResponse(), withItemResponse(), and submit().